# MySQL Workbench - Database Migration (SQL Server - > MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, migration

During the Source Object step we were asked to select what table/view/routines we want to migrate.

However as it create the schemata views and routines were skipped.
and I failed to find like a error log explaining why those are skipped.

I spent a good chunk of time researching on here and on google but no dice.
has anyone run into this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench Database Migration Wizard does not support view, stored procedures, triggers, functions..etc as of this day.

The only object is being migrated are the Tables